# SQL Server : single row output from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

Could you please guide me with the below requirement?

Data:

```
C_ID        A_ID        A_VAL        UPDATE_DATE    
------------------------------------------------
83181064    BDAY        2004         2021-08-26 
83181064    ANNIV                    2021-08-23 
83181064    EXPR        2006         2021-08-23
```

Expected output:

```
C_ID        A_ID_B    A_VAL_B       UPDATE_DATE_B   A_ID_N      A_VAL_N    UPDATE_DATE_N  A_ID_M      A_VAL_M       UPDATE_DATE_M
83181064    BDAY      2004          2021-08-26      ANNIV                  2021-08-23     EXPR        2006          2021-08-23
```

Comment: Do the various `A_ID` values need to appear in any certain order in the output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , it will be good if it appears in that order (as per the data).

Comment: why do you need this ? maybe if you tell more about your problem people here will give you much better solution ideas. I

Comment: Isnt this just conditional aggregation? There are plenty of examples here on how to achieve this if so. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @shruti M use pivot and unpivot

Comment: In which "order as per the data"? Tables have no inherent ordering and I see no column you could reasonably order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple join of table with itself as follows:
declaring table and its values

```
declare @t table(C_ID int, A_ID varchar(200), A_VAL varchar(200),UPDATE_DATE date);

insert into @t(C_ID, A_ID, A_VAL,UPDATE_DATE)
values
(83181064, 'BDAY', 2004,'2021-08-26'),
(83181064, 'ANNIV',null,'2021-08-23'),
(83181064,'EXPR', 2006,'2021-08-23')
```

multiple join of table with itself;

```
SELECT B.[C_ID],
B.A_ID AS A_ID_B,B.A_VAL AS A_VAL_B,B.UPDATE_DATE AS UPDATE_DATE_B,
N.A_ID AS A_ID_N,N.A_VAL AS A_VAL_N,N.UPDATE_DATE AS UPDATE_DATE_N,
M.A_ID AS A_ID_M,M.A_VAL AS A_VAL_M,M.UPDATE_DATE AS UPDATE_DATE_M
FROM @t B
INNER join @t N
on B.C_ID=N.C_ID 
INNER join @t M
on B.C_ID=M.C_ID 
WHERE B.A_ID='BDAY' AND N.A_ID='ANNIV' AND M.A_ID='EXPR'
```

Comment: I'm not sure multiple Joins would be the most performant here. Also, why the `LEFT JOIN`s when you make them implicit `INNER JOIN`s?

Comment: of course,  inner join can be use in here.the result would be the same

Comment: Thanks @RF1991 ,but output not getting in single row.

Comment: can you provide me with exact detail to solve your problem